# How to say "email me at this mail address"?

Tags: grammar, translation, email

I was wondering how I would say to someone that they can reach me at this email address or they can mail me here at this email address.

I would guess it would use the potential form of send for something like

> あなたは　メールを　username@email.comまで　おくれます。

Is this correct? Or how could I say it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to say it. Some of the common ways would be

「username@email.comまでメールください。」
「メールはこのアドレスまで（お願いします）。username@email.com」
「メールは下記アドレスまで。username@email.com」
「メールはこちらへどうぞ。username@email.com」

To a friend, you would say

「ここにメールしてね。username@email.com」

Comment: By the way, would it be good to say "username@email.comまでメールください**ね**" instead? What kind of difference would it make?

Comment: It's good too. ね would add a friendly, inviting tone.